# Como faço a chamada do file.setter usando Python para normalizar o nome do caminho

Tags: python, python-3.x

Codigo:

```
class Arquivos:
    @property
    def file(self):
        return self._file

    @file.setter
    def file(self, arquivo):
        if arquivo:
            self._file = os.path.abspath(arquivo)
```

Chamada:

```
Arquivos.file('usp/dados.json')
```

Erro:

```
File "/home/pc8454/faculdade/python/gerador.py", line 123, in <module>
    Arquivos.file('usp/dados.json')
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está utilizando uma propriedade, não definindo um método estático. Assim, você deverá criar a instância da sua classe e fazer a atribuição à propriedade:

```
arquivos = Arquivos()
arquivos.file = 'usp/dados.json'
```

Desta forma, a função definida em `@file.setter` será invocada como desejado.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou muito bem!!